# Custom Shopify Button embed on other website

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

I would like to embed a shopify buy button and checkout onto a separate website. I would like to customize it so it looks native. However, I can't figure out how I can do this such that I can have a completely custom CSS button and a separate button to open cart.

```
    var client = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
        domain: 'XXXX.myshopify.com',
        storefrontAccessToken: 'XXXX',
    });

    var ui = ShopifyBuy.UI.init(client);
    ui.createComponent('product', {
      id: XXXX,
      options: {
        product: {
          buttonDestination: 'cart',
        },
        cart: {
          startOpen: false,
        }
      }
    });

    ui.openCart();
```

Can't i just have a div that calls some function "AddToCart()"? Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use Shopify's 'Buy Button' sales channel.

After activating that channel, you can then use it to select a product or category. In this section, you can also alter the styling of the button etc. After everything is updated to your liking, click next and it will generate the code for the product or catalogue that you selected. Simply copy and paste the code that it generates on the website that you desire.

Hope this helps!